# Changing default html structure in WordPress nav menu

Tags: wordpress

By default, as everybody knows, Wordpress create a nav structure when you use the default menu function.

I have 10 items "li" (one per category) in the primary menu, and i'm trying add a different image into each "li". But I wish:

- Maintain the links to the categories into the ahref
- The content should be included into the ahref

Summarizing:

I want transform this

```
<li class="casilleroCat">
    <a href="https://categoryurl.com">Name of category2</a>
</li>
<li class="casilleroCat">
    <a href="https://categoryurl2.com">Name of category2</a>
</li>
```

into this

```
<li class="casilleroCat">
    <a href="https://categoryurl.com">
        <img src="https://url.com/customimage1.jpg" alt="name of cateogry"> 
        <br>
        <span>Name of category</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="casilleroCat">
    <a href="https://categoryurl2.com">
        <img src="https://url.com/customimage2.jpg" alt="name of category2"> 
        <br>
        <span>Name of category2</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

For that, I tried adding the following code in functions.php

```
/** FIRST, I CREATED THE MENUS **/
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

And now, i'm lost because i don't know **what it's the best way to achieve this**. Because if I add a code like this i'll lost the links created automatically by WordPress and I have to create a different function for each image.

```
function add_customHTML($items, $args) {
    if ($args->theme_location == 'Header Menu') { 

        // My html
        $item = '<li class="casilleroCat">
                    <a href="https://categoryurl.com">
                       <img src="https://url.com/customimage1.jpg" alt="name of cateogry"> 
                       <br>
                       <span>Name of category</span>
                   </a>
               </li>';
        $items = $item.$items;
    }
  return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_customHTML', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: this could be useful: https://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/

Comment: @DaFois Thank you, I added more info in my edited post. Issue resolved, but I lost page ancestor and related li info

Comment: I think that the main problem is solved. I'm going to open another post to the secondary problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I achieved with this snippet

```
function clean_custom_menus() {
    $menu_name = 'header-menu'; // specify custom menu slug
    if (($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$menu_name])) {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_name]);
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

        $menu_list = '<nav>' ."\n";
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t". '<ul>' ."\n";
        foreach ((array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item) {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;
            $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t\t". '<li class="casilleroCat"><a href="'. $url .'"><img src="imagen'. $a++ .'.jpg"><br><span>'. $title .'</span></a></li>' ."\n";
        }
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t". '</ul>' ."\n";
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t". '</nav>' ."\n";
    } else {
        // $menu_list = '<!-- no list defined -->';
    }
    echo $menu_list;
}
```

And calling the function in the page with this code

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'extra-menu' ) ); ?>
```